# Form Validation- html and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation

I'm relatively new to coding- working on form validation and can't get the page to actually return false (not submit the form if the user inputs the incorrect isbn length) with my formValidation function. Wondering what I'm missing here.

The alert pops up and form is submitted no matter what the isbn.length is- however, if it's the correct length, it does get added to the database and is rerouted to the home page. If it's not the right length, it's routed to 
"This page isn’t working
localhost didn’t send any data.
ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE"

---

Javascript:

```
//function to validate the form's ISBN number input and ensure it's between 10-14 digits.

function formValidation(){
    var isbn = document.forms["sellForm"]["isbn"];

        if (isbn.length >= 10 && isbn.length <= 14){
         return true;

     }
     else
     {
         alert("Please input a 10-14 digit ISBN number");
         isbn.focus();
         return false;

     }
 }

</script>
```

corresponding HTML:

```
<form name="sellForm" method="POST" action="/create" role="form" onsubmit="formValidation()">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role" >ISBN</label>
                <input type="number" size=14 class="form-control" name="isbn" id="role"  required
               placeholder="input the 10-14 digit ISBN number"/>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="age">Condition</label>
                                    <br>
   <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Very Used"> Very Used<br>
     <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Lightly Used"> Lightly Used<br>
     <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Like New"> Like New
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" required
                                placeholder="input whole dollar price">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add-btn">
                                <span class="fa fa-fire"></span> Sell</button>

            </form>
```

Comment: Do you hit the alert? Any console errors (hit F12 to bring up browser tools then go to the "Console" tab)?

Comment: What does "can't get the page to actual return false" mean?

Comment: What does `console.log(isbn)` tell you when placed right after you set that variable? Is it defined? Also, "10-12 digits", or "10-14"? Alert msg says one, code & placeholder text say the other.

Comment: it should be 10-14. checking console.log(isbn)

Comment: no console errors. I added additional context in the description.

Comment: a. you should change`var isbn = document.forms["sellForm"]["isbn"];` to `var isbn = document.forms["sellForm"]["isbn"].value;`
b. and, you should debug the `isbn` value. in web browser, hit f12 to go to "Console tab", type like `console.log(isbn)`.
c. `onsubmit="return formValidation()"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have other issues (see [Andre's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175443/4665)) but you need to add `return` as part of the `onsubmit` attribute

```
<form name="sellForm" method="POST" action="/create" role="form" onsubmit="return formValidation();">
```

The Full Version

```js
function formValidation() {  
  /*This is the form element*/ 
  var isbnEl = document.forms["sellForm"]["isbn"];
  var isbn = isbnEl.value;
  
  /*The following 2 lines are for demonstration only and can be removed*/
  console.log(isbnEl);
  console.log(isbn);
  
  if (isbn.length >= 10 && isbn.length <= 14) {
    return true;

  } else {
    alert("Please input a 10-12 digit ISBN number");
    isbnEl.focus();
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="sellForm" method="POST" action="/create" role="form" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="role">ISBN</label>
    <input type="number" size=14 class="form-control" name="isbn" id="role" required placeholder="input the 10-14 digit ISBN number" />
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="age">Condition</label>
    <br>
    <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Very Used"> Very Used<br>
    <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Lightly Used"> Lightly Used<br>
    <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Like New"> Like New
  </div>
  <!--</div> <---- This is an orphan tag, remove it -->

  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Price</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" required placeholder="input whole dollar price">
  </div>

  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add-btn">
                                <span class="fa fa-fire"></span> Sell</button>

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to check isbn.value like this:

```
function formValidation(){
  var isbn = document.forms["sellForm"]["isbn"];

  if (isbn.value >= 10 && isbn.value <= 14) {
       return true;
  } else {
       alert("Please input a 10-12 digit ISBN number");
       isbn.focus();
       return false;
  }
}
```

Then add the logic as desired.

Comment: I think he is not checking the value but the length if the length is between 10 and 14.

Comment: The html control is a numeric control, base on the isbn number, I think is not the length what was trying to check.

Comment: It works for me, could you explain more what you are trying to accomplish in order to send you a full example.

Comment: @AndreGamboa Your answer seems to be incorrect. You must check the value's length like this: `isbn.value.length`. See my answer it contains a runnable snippet.

Comment: I see what you are saying, you are correct, it should be isbn.value.length

Answer (score 1):

You need to check for the `isbn` input field value's length, and in the form tag you need to get the `formValidation` function's return in the `onsubmit` handler like this: `onsubmit="return formValidation()"`.

```js
function formValidation(){
    var isbn = document.forms["sellForm"]["isbn"];
        // check for the input field value's length
        if (isbn.value.length >= 10 && isbn.value.length <= 14){
         return true;

     }
     else
     {
         alert("Please input a 10-12 digit ISBN number");
         isbn.focus();
         return false;

     }
 }
```

```html
<form name="sellForm" method="POST" action="/create" role="form" onsubmit="return formValidation()">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="role" >ISBN</label>
                <input type="number" size=14 class="form-control" name="isbn" id="role"  required
               placeholder="input the 10-14 digit ISBN number"/>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                  <label for="age">Condition</label>
                                    <br>
   <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Very Used"> Very Used<br>
     <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Lightly Used"> Lightly Used<br>
     <input type="radio" name="book_condition" value="Like New"> Like New
                  </div>
              </div>

              <div class="form-group">
                <label>Price</label>
                <input type="number" class="form-control" name="price" required
                                placeholder="input whole dollar price">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" id="add-btn">
                                <span class="fa fa-fire"></span> Sell</button>

            </form>
```

Comment: That's same with me.

Comment: @WhitehorseJJ what ? I didn't get it ?!

Comment: Don't worry. it doesn't mean. ths.

Comment: @WhitehorseJJ what are you trying to say ?

Comment: That's nothing. you're very quick and intelligent.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179421/discussion-between-whitehorsejj-and-ths).